# Remove rows where all values of a column are identical, based on another column

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this:

```
id    info
1     0
1     0
2     0
2     10
3     20
3     20
```

I want to remove the rows for all "id"s that have no change in their "info", that is, remove all rows where the "info" is identical for a certain "id".

For the example above, I would end up:

```
id    info
2     0
2     10
```

Comment: base R: `subset(df, ave(info, id, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x))) > 1)`

Comment: the `dplyr` solution would be `df %>% group_by(id) %>% filter(length(unique(info))>1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A base R solution,

```
df[!with(df, ave(info, id, FUN = function(i)var(i) == 0)),]
#slightly different syntax (as per @lmo)
#df[ave(df$info, df$id, FUN=var) > 0,]
```

which gives,

> ```
>   id info
> 3  2    0
> 4  2   10
> ```

Comment: You beat me. I had `dat[ave(dat$info, dat$id, FUN=var) > 0,]`.

Comment: @lmo I like that syntax better. I m adding it :)

Comment: For `df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3), info=c(0,0,0,10,10,20,20))` there are two rows `2 10` in the result; imho this is not the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with `data.table`:

```
library("data.table")
DT <- fread(
"id    info
1     0
1     0
2     0
2     10
3     20
3     20")
DT[, .N, .(id, info)][N==1, .(id, info)]
# > DT[, .N, .(id, info)][N==1, .(id, info)]
#    id info
# 1:  2    0
# 2:  2   10
```

a variant:

```
DT[, if (.N==1) TRUE, .(id, info)][, .(id, info)]
```

Here is a solution using an anti-join:

```
DT[!DT[duplicated(DT)], on=names(DT)]
```

Answer (score -1):

Another `data.table` solution using `.SD` magic variable.

```
df <- data.table(id = c(1,1,2,2,3,3), info=c(0,0,0,10,20,20))

df[,.SD[uniqueN(.SD)>1],id]

    id info
1:  2    0
2:  2   10
```

Comment: Sorry and thanks for bringing it up :)

Comment: For `df <- data.table(id = c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3), info=c(0,0,0,10,10,20,20))` it will produce not the desired result.

Comment: Did you try running this one? It does give the output as expected.

Comment: Yes I tried it. I got the row `2 10` twice.